# Send email after Exception raised continuosly for more than one hour

Tags: python, exception

I have a Python program that deals with a webpage with Selenium every 5 minutes from a cron job. cron sends me an email for every exception raised (cron just catches all stderr). Sometimes the website has some persistent internal errors, and I end up with hundreds of system emails to check. I then started ignoring exceptions, but I found it would be more sane if the program would send me an email if the problem persists for one hour.

I have written the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, os, time

name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])

def send_email(server, message):
    # just print for testing
    print('Sending email...')

def handle_exception(exception, function):
    # save a state file in /dev/shm with the name of the exception
    warn_state = '/dev/shm/{}.{}'.format(name, exception.__name__)
    try:
        function
    except(exception) as exception:
        if os.path.exists(warn_state):
            if time.time() - os.path.getmtime(warn_state) > 3600:
                send_email('localhost', exception.args[1])
        else:
            open(warn_state, 'w').close()
    else:
        if os.path.exists(warn_state):
            os.remove(warn_state)

def my_function():
    # try raising a NameError
    print(undefined_variable)

# run my_function() catching exceptions
handle_exception(NameError, my_function)
```

When I run the code above, I have checked that the **`else:` part is being executed, indicating that `function` is not failing at all**. I'm new to programming, so I don't really know if this would be the proper way to do this, but I created this function because I have to deal with at least five different types of exceptions on this script, that are raised randomly by Selenium due to server or network problems.

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: @scytale `function` is not raising a NameError when run from `handle_exception`.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler approach would be to log errors to a file, then run a separate job to summarize the log, say, hourly.

Comment: you're masking `exception` - you should change the line to `except exception as e` - i'm not sure if that's the cause of your problem tho.

Comment: for someone new to programming you're doing ok with higher order techniques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not actually calling `function`

```
function
```

does nothing. you need to do

```
function()
```